# Finding a power series representation for the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ with the center of the series at a = 1

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm slightly stuck on a homework question. I'm supposed to:

(a) Find a power series representation for the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $ with the center of the series at $a = 1$ by realizing that $f$ is the sum of a convergent geometric series. Then, find the series interval and radius of convergence using the established fact that a geometric series, $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1}$, converges when $|r| < 1$.

(b) Find the Taylor series expansion of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} $ about $a = 1$, making sure to show steps involved in finding the coefficients $c_n = \frac{f^n(a)}{n!}$. Then, using the ratio test, find the series interval and radius of convergence.

So far, this is what I've figured out so far:

(a) Because it is given that $f$ is the sum of a geometric series, and we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ar^{n-1} $ sums to $\frac{a}{1-r}$ when $|r| < 1$, we can put $f$ in the form $f(x) = \frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{1}{1-1+x} = \frac{1}{1-(1-x)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1(1-x)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1(1-x)^n$ .

(b) I found the Taylor series for $f(x) = \frac {1}{x}$ about $a=1$ and ended up with $$\frac{1}{x} = 1+(-1)+\frac{2}{2!}(x-1)^2+\frac{-6}{3!}(x-1)^3+\frac{24}{4!}(x-1)^4+... $$$$= 1-(x-1)+(x-1)^2-(x-1)^3+(x-1)^4+...$$

I know I still have to figure out a very large chunk of these problems. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ${1 \over x} = {1 \over 1+(x-1)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (x-1)^k$ for $|x-1|<1$.

Comment: Your answer looks find to me, what is your question?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the Taylor series to do the ratio test and find the series interval and radius of convergence for part b.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

To expand $ f(x) $ around $ x=a$, You define $g(x)=f(x+a)$ and you expand $ g(x) $ around $ x=0 $.

You get
$$g(x)=P_n(x) + x^n\epsilon_1(x)$$
with
$$\lim_0\epsilon_1(x)=0$$
then you will have

$$f(x)=g(x-a)=P_n(x-a) + (x-a)^n\epsilon_2(x)$$
with
$$\lim_a\epsilon_2(x)=0$$

In your case,
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
$$=1-x+x^2-x^3+...+(-1)^nx^n+x^n\epsilon_1(x)$$